# Upload file to sharepoint 2007 using .net framework 4

Tags: .net-4.0, sharepoint-2007

i want to make an application to upload files to SharePoint 2007 programatically  with . net framework 4.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Copy` Web service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/copy%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

You cannot utilize the SharePoint object model in a .NET Framework 4 application because SharePoint 2007 is built on .NET Framework 2.0, but you can access its Web services from any platform.